# How to use DISTINCT in ms access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AwardDescriptions.aID, CostCentres.cCC 
FROM  AwardDescriptions 
INNER JOIN CostCentres ON AwardDescriptions.aID = CostCentres.cNumber 
ORDER BY CostCentres.cCC;
```

For some reason, when I run my query, it still shows all duplicate values.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You see duplicate rows with the same  aID *and* cCC ?

Comment: @AlexK. I see where I could have gone wrong now... ok question rephrased: How do I modify my query so that there are no duplicate costcentres?

Comment: Well if there are 2 different cCC values for a single specific aID, which one do you want? You would pick an aggregate (e.g. `min()/max()`) and use `GROUP BY`

Comment: @carrots can you some sample data and the result you'd want to get for it?

Comment: @AlexK. There can be 2 different cCC for one aID, and similairly there can be 2 different aID for one cCC. I don't really care about the aID, I just want it to render all distinct values of the cCC.

Comment: @Mureinik aID cCC
37 600002
38 600003
39 600004
9 600005
45 600007
40 600008
41 600009
20 600239
**97 600239**
17 600279
**19 600279**


So the bolded ones shouldn't be appearing, but they do.

Comment: @AlexK. it's impossible to understand anything in the comments like this. Can you please edit your question with this (properly formatted) information?

Comment: @Mureinik not my question :)

Comment: @AlexK. apologies, that was meant at OP (carrots) - must have looked at the wrong line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and get either the minimum or maximum value:

```
SELECT MAX(AwardDescriptions.aID) as aID, CostCentres.cCC 
FROM  AwardDescriptions INNER JOIN
      CostCentres
      ON AwardDescriptions.aID = CostCentres.cNumber 
GROUP BY CostCentres.cCC
ORDER BY CostCentres.cCC;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I'm having a hard time understanding why using MAX and GROUP BY makes this work. I thought MAX will get a single value from aID which is highest, but how does it then render all the aID?

Comment: @carrots . . . I don't understand your question.  This query shows one value of `aID` for each `CostCenter.cCC`, which appears to be what your question is asking.